# Selecting id of form being submitted to put in jquery variable

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I'm making a jokes website. Each joke is stored in a record in mysql db. When the jokes are put together on a page, there is a vote button with the `class=votebutton`. When someone clicks this, I'd like the id of the form and the user's IP address sent via jquery's ajax function to my vote processing .php file. I have 2 questions:
1. Is it right to use `$(".votebutton").click()` as the selector to run this function?
2. How do I select the `id` of the form being submitted to construct the id variable in the jquery function?

```
 $(function() {
      $(".votebutton").click(function() {
      var id = //I'd like this to be the id of the form submitted
      var ip = //I'd like this to be the ip of the user
      var dataString = 'id='+ id = '&ip=' + ip;
      //alert (dataString);return false;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/vote.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
          //something to do on success
        }
      });
      return false;
   });
 });
```

Also, one more question if you guys have a minute - what is a good way to get the IP of the visitor. I expect there to be about 10 of these forms per page (one for each joke)...

Thanks very much for the help...

Comment: separate form is needed for each vote button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it right to use
>   $(".votebutton").click() as the
>   selector

Yes

> How do I select the id of the form
>   being submitted

Common practice is to store the ID as part of the element ID, for example:

```
<button id="vote_54321" value="Vote!" class="votebutton" />
```

Than, in your function you can get the ID:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
```

There is no way to get the client IP from javascript, that you should get it in your serverside php code:

```
$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It's better to use 'submit' as the event - this way you can use tab and return to navigate to the form element. You attach the submit handler to the form, not the button.
2. If you use 'submit' then 'this' will already be the form so you can do `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

It's correct to use .votebutton for the  click.

When you click the button just access the id of the parent so $(this).parent().attr('id')

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes that should work fine. It'll bind all elements with that class
2. `jQuery(this).attr('id')` should provide you with the the ID of the element.

Not sure about the IP though.